# Android, track Memory by DDMS, "Get Allocations" doesn't do anything

Tags: android, memory-management, ddms

As the title of the question said. Steps I did:

1. click on Update heap
2. In Allocation Tracker tab, click "Start Tracking"
3. Click "Get Allocations"

In the console, I saw red messages saying:

> [2013-12-29 13:56:40 - ddm-heap] *** Received REAL`

What happened? am I missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to "Get Allocations"? My DDMS on Debian testing retrieves nothing from my usb connected device despite it seeing the phone and app/threads etc.

Answer (score 5):

It needs to be done in Android Studio. (Thanks to the Project Member who said this on this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=74059)

You can see that the icons even have the same name as the icons in DDMS (which is confusing)!  But the Allocation Tracker in DDMS does not work, and the one in Android Studio "Android Monitor" does.

P.S. In the screenshots I was using Android Studio 2.3 and Android Device Monitor version 25.2.2.

**Wrong (Does not work):**

[image: DDMS Monitor (does not work)]

**Right (works):**

[image: Android Monitor in Android Studio]

The results will show up in a window next to your source code like this:

[image]

For more info:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html  https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-allocation.html

Answer (score 4):

Well, REAL is a REcent ALlocation.
Based on the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/source/browse/trunk/java/AndroidScreenMonitor/src/com/android/ddmlib/HandleHeap.java?r=16), logging an error is the very first line of handleREAL(). Just an assumption - this should be Log.d() instead of Log.e(), but I cannot say for sure.

And yes, "Get Allocations" for me works not every time I click it. The resulting log cannot be exported, and disappears as soon as the app on device finishes. Sadly, not a very convenient tracing tool...

Comment: Does this tool print this error message when it works as well? Or only when it doesn't work?

Comment: If my assumption about the source code is correct - then this log message doesn't indicate an error (should be a Debug level message).

Comment: Okay. In reply to myself: this tool does print the error message, even when it works. It, uhh, could stand to be better, Google.